# Automatically cleanup tmp directory in Unix

Tags: linux, unix, debian-based

I am implementing my own file cache server using Play framework, and I put my cached files in `/tmp` directory.

However I do not know how the OS manages the `/tmp` directory. What I wish to know is if the OS will automatically cleanup some files that are old enough, or have not been accessed for a long time.

I am running my server in a Docker container, based on Debian jessie.

Comment: Not that it matters for your question, but is `/tmp` mounted from the host OS or inside the Docker container?

Comment: I am having it mounted inside the Docker container. I think it would be interesting to mount the volume with the host OS, and have another container do the cleanup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your OS won't clean up `/tmp`. Some Unix variants clear it out at reboot. You will need to do this yourself.

```
 find /tmp/yourpath -mtime +30 -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

For example.

But Docker is a bit of a special case, as the containers are an encapsulation layer. That `find` will still do the trick, but you could probably just dump and restart your container 'fresh' and trash the old one.

Comment: I am not familiar with the command you have above. Does it clean the /tmp directory every 30 minutes?

Comment: Nope. Read the man page on `find`. It deletes any files older than 30 days old. And runs once. You can add it to `cron` to run more regularly.

Comment: I will tinker with this solution, thanks Sobrique! :)